# Pointer in copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a copy constructor that looks like this:

```
Qtreenode(const QtreeNode * & n) {

    x=n->x;
    y=n->y;
    height=n->height;
    width=n->width;
    element=n->element;
```

}

I wrote this a week ago, and I looked back at it today and I was surprised by the line that when called the copy constructor with say `swChild=new QtreeNode(*(n->swChild));` The arguement to the cc is a pointer by reference, right? But when I call it, I do (*(n->swChild)), which means the value of that child right? Why does my code work?

Comment: Are you using a smart pointer for the four child pointers?  If not, this class is not exception safe:  if an exception is thrown by any of the allocations or creations, you'll leak `QtreeNode` objects.

Comment: Ya I'm getting a ton of valgrind errors. I think this may be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a copy constructor.  A copy constructor for a class is a constructor that takes a reference of the class's type.  Any of the following would be copy constructors, though the second, taking a const reference, is by far the most commonly used:

```
QTreeNode(QTreeNode&);
QTreeNode(const QTreeNode&);
QTreeNode(volatile QTreeNode&);
QTreeNode(const volatile QTreeNode&);
```

Since this isn't a copy constructor, the implicitly declared copy constructor is still provided.  It is declared as `QTreeNode(const QTreeNode& n)` and basically just copies each member of the class (i.e., it's a "shallow" copy, not a "deep" copy).  It is this implicitly declared copy constructor that is used in your code.

Comment: What do you mean? What am I missing that would make it a copy constructor?

Comment: Still not understanding. Right now this is not a copy constructor but it does indeed make shallow copies? I want to be making deep copies though. So would I just remove the the pointer in the argument? Or what would have to change?

Comment: @bitmoe: you're not missing. You have one character more than needed: `*`.

Comment: @bitmoe: What @ybungalobill said: your copy constructor can't take a pointer, it has to take a reference. You need to remove the `*` (making the parameter a reference to a `QTreeNode` instead of a reference to a pointer to a `QTreeNode`) and update the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: Wait a minute-is my function, considering that it has been fixed to be a copy constructor, recursing to copy my entire subtree of the given node? Because I call the copy constructor from my operator= overload to make a copy of the source's root node like this `root=new QtreeNode(*(source.root))`, and what I want it to do is copy the entire subtree of root by recursion. Am I accomplishing this with my function?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a copy constructor, it's just a regular old constructor. A copy constructor would take a `const QtreeNode&`, not a `const QtreeNode*&`.

Since you didn't define a copy constructor, the compiler made one for you. That's the one that is being called in the line `swChild=new QtreeNode(*(n->swChild));`, since you are passing a `QtreeNode` and not a pointer to one.